# Timepicker-addon doesn't show - Datepicker works fine?

Tags: custom-post-types, jquery, metabox, jquery-ui

**UPDATE**
It seems that it might be a problem with the,

```
  $("#opening_time").datetimepicker();
  $("#opening_time_end").timepicker();
  $("#closing_time_end").timepicker();
```

If there is a `datetimepicker` call before a `timepicker` then the `timepicker` doesn't work.  I do not understand since I have the `datepicker` working and everything is included in the same way.  What am I missing?

Succesfully added the jQuery UI Datepicker and even added a time picker for just time `meta_box` fields.  I have been trying to ad Trent Richardson's Timepicker-addon and I can not get it to show up.

Here is the `wp-enqueue` in functions.php.

```
      /**
   * Adds a jQuery datepicker script to Event pages.
   * http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/
   */
  function pbd_events_jquery_datepicker() {
      wp_enqueue_script(
          'jquery-ui-datepicker',
          get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/jquery-ui-datepicker/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js',
          array('jquery')
      );
          wp_enqueue_script(
          'jquery-ui-timepicker',
          get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/jquery-ui-datepicker/jquery.ui.timepicker.js',
          array('jquery')
      );
      wp_enqueue_script(
          'jquery-ui-timepicker-addon',
          get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/jquery-ui-datepicker/jquery.ui.timepicker-addon.js',
          array('jquery')
      );

      wp_enqueue_script(
          'pbd-datepicker',
          get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/jquery-ui-datepicker/pbd-datepicker.js',
          array('jquery', 'jquery-ui-datepicker', 'jquery-ui-timepicker', 'jquery-ui-timepicker-addon')
      );
  }
  add_action('admin_print_scripts-post-new.php', 'pbd_events_jquery_datepicker');
  add_action('admin_print_scripts-post.php', 'pbd_events_jquery_datepicker');

  /**
   * Adds CSS for the jQuery datepicker script to Event pages.
   * http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/
   */
  function pbd_events_jquery_datepicker_css() {
      wp_enqueue_style(
          'jquery-ui-datepicker',
          get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/jquery-ui-datepicker/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css'
      );
      wp_enqueue_style(
          'jquery-ui-timepicker',
          get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/jquery-ui-datepicker/css/jquery.ui.timepicker.css'
      );
      wp_enqueue_style(
          'jquery-ui-timepicker-addon',
          get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/jquery-ui-datepicker/css/jquery.ui.timepicker-addon.css'
      );
  }
  add_action('admin_print_styles-post-new.php', 'pbd_events_jquery_datepicker_css');
  add_action('admin_print_styles-post.php', 'pbd_events_jquery_datepicker_css');
```

Here is the function call in pbd-datepicker that is added in the `wp-enqueue`.

```
      jQuery(function($) {
      $( "#start_date" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd', numberOfMonths: 2, minDate: 0 });
      $( "#end_date" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd', numberOfMonths: 4 });               

      $("#opening_time").datetimepicker();

      $("#opening_time_end").timepicker();
      $("#closing_time_end").timepicker();
      $("#artist_talk_time_end").timepicker();
      $("#lecture_time_end").timepicker();
      $("#panel_time_end").timepicker();
      $("#special_event_time_end").timepicker();
      $("#workshop_time_end").datetimepicker();
  });
```

The input field `id`s are accurate.  I have checked and double-checked typos.  Why would the first two scripts, jquery.ui.timepicker.js and datepicker work but not jquery.ui.timepicker-addon.js??

Am I calling the js wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out that I needed to have the right js dependencies declared.  This code now works.  Hope it helps someone else with the same problem.

Key line `array('jquery-ui-core' ,'jquery-ui-datepicker', 'jquery-ui-slider')`

Full `wp-enqueue' code:

```
      function pbd_events_jquery_datepicker() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
          'jquery-ui-datepicker',
          get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/jquery-ui-datepicker/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js',
          array('jquery')
      );

        wp_enqueue_script(
          'jquery-ui-timepicker-addon',
          get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/jquery-ui-datepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js',
          array('jquery-ui-core' ,'jquery-ui-datepicker', 'jquery-ui-slider')
      );

      wp_enqueue_script(
          'pbd-datepicker',
          get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/jquery-ui-datepicker/pbd-datepicker.js',
          array('jquery', 'jquery-ui-datepicker' , 'jquery-ui-timepicker-addon')
      );
  }
  add_action('admin_print_scripts-post-new.php', 'pbd_events_jquery_datepicker');
  add_action('admin_print_scripts-post.php', 'pbd_events_jquery_datepicker');

  /**
   * Adds CSS for the jQuery datepicker script to Event pages.
   * http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/
   */
  function pbd_events_jquery_datepicker_css() {
      wp_enqueue_style(
          'jquery-ui-datepicker',
          get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/jquery-ui-datepicker/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css'
      );
      wp_enqueue_style(
          'jquery-ui-timepicker-addon',
          get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/jquery-ui-datepicker/css/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css'
      );
  }
  add_action('admin_print_styles-post-new.php', 'pbd_events_jquery_datepicker_css');
  add_action('admin_print_styles-post.php', 'pbd_events_jquery_datepicker_css');
```

Comment: Cool One-Liner: array('jquery-ui-core' ,'jquery-ui-datepicker', 'jquery-ui-slider')

Comment: Thank you for documenting this working solution. Works fine using wp_register_script and then wp_enqueue_script too.